# MySQL - insert into with foreign key index

Tags: mysql, insert, bulkinsert, insert-update, lastinsertid

Here is the scenario:
I have 2 tables and 2 temporary tables.  Before I insert user data to the official tables, I insert them to a temp table to let them do the checks.  There is a `company` table with company info, and a `contact` table that has contact info.  The `contact` table has a field called `company_id` which is a foreign key index for the `company` table.

Temp tables are set up the same way.

I want to do something like: `INSERT INTO company () SELECT * FROM temp_company;` and `INSERT INTO contact () SELECT * FROM temp_contact`

My question is, how do I transfer the foreign key from the `temp_company` to the newly inserted id on the `company` table using a statement like this?  Is there a way to do it?

Currently I am:

1. grabbing the temp rows
2. going one by one and inserting them
3. grabbing the last insert id
4. then inserting the contacts afterwards with the new last insert id

I just don't know if that is the most efficient way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the same number of columns in both tables and then you should just be able to use the syntax you have there? Just take out the `()`. Just make sure there aren't any duplicate primary keys:

```
INSERT INTO company SELECT * FROM temp_company;
INSERT INTO contact SELECT * FROM temp_contact;
```

You can also specifically specify the columns that get inserted, this way you can specify exactly which column you insert as the new ID.

```
INSERT INTO company (`ID`,`col_1`,...,`last_col`) SELECT `foreign_key_col`,`col_1`,...,`last_col` FROM temp_company;
INSERT INTO contact (`ID`,`col_1`,...,`last_col`) SELECT `foreign_key_col`,`col_1`,...,`last_col` FROM temp_contact;
```

Just make sure you are selecting the right # of columns.

Comment: The only issue is I am not populating an empty table with the temp table data.  I am adding rows to a table that already has a bunch of data.

Comment: Right that should be fine, is the problem that you don't know if you have duplicate keys before the insert?  If this is the case, then you can use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY INGNORE` syntax, depending on what you want to do.